# Can i post a task to a specific location in a project through asana API?

Tags: asana

I'm trying to post a task within a project under a certain section, does anyone have any suggestions as to go about doing it/ is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are in luck! We are *right now* working on improving our support for sections in the API.

To add a task to a given section, you can use the `addProject` method with a `section` parameter, which is similar to `insert_before` or `insert_after`. An example call would look like `POST /tasks/1234/addProject?project=111&section=7865`.

Now, that's an extra call you need to make after you create the task, which is a bummer, so we're *also* working on a way to specify sections when you create the task. But we're literally working on that right now. I'll edit this answer when that exists.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer! one more quick question, what call would I use to add a task into a specific project?

Comment: also, am I able to create a new section through the api

Comment: `addProject` is used both to add a task to a project as well as position it (with insert_before, insert_after, or section). And a section is just a task that ends with a colon (`:`), so you can create one the same way you create a task (just make sure the name field ends with a colon, like `"P1:"`).

Comment: hi again, one more question, what would I write as the data when I use the addProject with the Section parameter?

Comment: Ira - { project: [project id], section: [id of section task] }

Comment: is there anyway to get the project owner?

Comment: Not currently, though we'll probably add this when we add things like project status. Not ETA on that as of yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

To POST a new task to a project in a specific section (column) hit the workspace URL

`https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/[workspace-id]/tasks`

You need to declare the memberships property in your POST request, the API documentation makes this very confusing.

Here is how it should be:

`"memberships": [{
  "project": 12345,
  "section": 12345
}]`

The API documentation makes it seem like you need to also include the name that goes along with the project and section.

Here is their example from the docs which is NOT how it should be done:

`[{ project: { id: 1331, name: 'Bugs' }, section: { id: 1123, name: 'P1:' } }]`

I found this answer here: https://community.asana.com/t/how-create-task-with-membership-via-api/10481/2